# .NET: Can I export an XML document-as-resource to disk using reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection

Gents -

Been a while since I played with this stuff, so I don't know if the idea below is realistic and/or possible. Can someone let me know if this is a viable approach and where it ranks in terms of kludginess?

Scenario:

- I have an XML document which represents the design/metadata of a report
- This document will be temporarily published to a server where it is executed.
- Publishing occurs by spinning up a 3rd-party console app and pointing it to said XML document.
- The server will return the output of the report to the user, then delete the published XML doc on the server itself.
- I'd prefer not to leave the XML document lying around permanently on the file system where a curious user might find it and muck around with it.

Question:

I assumne I could embed the XML document as a resource in an assembly. Could I then **use reflection to grab the resource and write it to disk** so I can point my 3rd-party console app at it? Plan would be to delete it off the disk as soon as the "publish" to the server was complete.

Just looking for general feedback on the idea and if there are smarter ways to approach this scenario - there normally are!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure could do that.  Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820384/reading-embedded-xml-file-c-sharp) for some details on how to implement your reasonable (to me, at least) idea. I like the "the code is in control" over "hopeful configuration management" concept.