# ReadXml Embedded Resource

Tags: c#

How can I read xml in Embedded Resource?

Is the code below correct? The xml is at the root of the project folder

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml("text.xml");
```

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading embedded XML file c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820384/reading-embedded-xml-file-c-sharp)

Comment: And covered in details on [How to embed and access resources by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) which can be found by searching for [howto c# read Embedded Resource](http://www.bing.com/search?q=howto+c%23+read+Embedded+Resource&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=howto+c%23+read+embedded+resource&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=)