# Open an embedded resource file without create the file in application directory

Tags: c#

How to open an embedded resource file without create the file in application directory, because all methods i tried creates the file in application directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
var manifestResource = Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("myfile.xml");
```

Then you can work with a manifestResource in memory with a streamReader.

Look at the full example of David in this post, this might help you

[Reading embedded XML file c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820384/reading-embedded-xml-file-c-sharp)

[]'s